# Why is my Unity plane seemingly 10 times too big

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm a relative Unity noob. I have a fairly simple scene. Currently in the following you will see a plane (object WorldTilemapGfx) and 2 sprites (Tile C: 0 R: 0, and Tile C: 1 R: 0).

In the following picture you see I've selected one of the sprites. Its scale is 1 x 1, and its at position 1, 0.
[image]

Now I select the other sprite.
[image]

So far the positions and sizes seem ok.

Now if I select the game object with a "plane" mesh it shows in the inspector as scale 2, 1. This is the scale I expect since it is supposed to be as wide as two of the tiles above, and as high as only 1 of them.

However its visually 10 times too big.

[image]

If I increase the X scale of one of my tiles by 10, then the relative sizes between tile and plane look ok

[image]

Also the image used for my tile is 256 x 256.
[image]

[image]
Can someone suggest what I am missing? Thanks.

Comment: I think I found the reason: 

https://forum.unity.com/threads/really-dumb-question-scale-of-plane-compared-to-cube.33835/#:~:text=aNTeNNa%20trEE%20said%3A-,The%20plane%20is%20a%2010x10%20unit%20mesh.,a%20quick%20floor%20or%20wall.

Answer (score 0):

See [Unity Mesh Primitives](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PrimitiveObjects.html)

> **Plane**
>
> This is a flat square with **edges ten units long** oriented in the XZ plane of the local coordinate space. It is textured so that the whole image appears exactly once within the square. A plane is useful for most kinds of flat surface, such as floors and walls. A surface is also needed sometimes for showing images or movies in GUI and special effects. Although a plane can be used for things like this, the simpler quad primitive is often a more natural fit to the task.

whereas

> **Quad**
>
> The quad primitive resembles the plane but its **edges are only one unit long** and the surface is oriented in the XY plane of the local coordinate space. Also, a quad is divided into just two triangles whereas the plane contains two hundred. A quad is useful in cases where a scene object must be used simply as a display screen for an image or movie. Simple GUI and information displays can be implemented with quads, as can particles, sprites
> and “impostor” images that substitute for solid objects viewed at a distance.

Answer (score -1):

Ok.. confirmed using a Quad gave me what I expected in scale.. I now understand that the underlying plane mesh is actually 10 x 10 in size.

[https://forum.unity.com/threads/really-dumb-question-scale-of-plane-compared-to-cube.33835/#:~:text=aNTeNNa%20trEE%20said%3A-,The%20plane%20is%20a%2010x10%20unit%20mesh.,a%20quick%20floor%20or%20wall](https://forum.unity.com/threads/really-dumb-question-scale-of-plane-compared-to-cube.33835/#:%7E:text=aNTeNNa%20trEE%20said%3A-,The%20plane%20is%20a%2010x10%20unit%20mesh.,a%20quick%20floor%20or%20wall).